# Ubuntu Studio 21.04 Recent Files Removal

Tags: 20.04

I have only had Ubuntu Studio 21.04 for a short time. I am unable to remove any files from Recent. Before there was a way to remove them right from the file itself. I have looked for command line ways to do it and have had no result there. This has included several different ways.

Comment: Look in `System Settings`>`Workspace Behaviour`>`Activities`>`Privacy`. Remind that your version of Ubuntu is not supported anymore, consider installing a recent release as soon as possible.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Please clarify your details; you've tagged *20.04* or the 2020-April, but also 21.04 or the 2021-April release whichhad a single upgrade path being to 21.10 alas that closed when [21.10 went EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/) nine months after release. Neither 20.04 nor 21.04 of Ubuntu Studio has upgrade paths anymore; [20.04](https://ubuntustudio.org/2023/04/ubuntu-studio-20-04-has-reached-end-of-life/) as it was the last using Xfce, and 21.04's upgrade path went on EOL of the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I upgraded to the latest distribution. Didn't realize what one I was working with.

Comment: Your details are still unclear; this is a Q&A site and answers will be to your question and not involve *comments* which are intended for readers asking questions about that question (ie. not for replies; if corrections/clarifications need to be performed they're to be made to the question itself).  21.04 has no upgrade path except to 21.10 but that was gone with 21.10 reached EOL, and 20.04 had no upgrade path as it was the last Xfce desktop... thus upgrade to any *later* isn't supported. The latest is 23.04 which is available for upgrades from 22.10 - which you don't mention.